# How can I pause a thread or save an image of a thread in Common Lisp?

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, sbcl

I'd like to be able to pause the execution of a computationally intensive thread when the user clicks a pause button and pick up where it left off when the user clicks on a button to resume computation. But I'd ideally also like to avoid **busy waiting**. One option is to serialize the state of the thread and terminate the thread when pausing. When resuming, I can start a new thread and deserialize the state of the prior thread.

However, it occurs to me that in Common Lisp I can save the state of a running program via something like `(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die)` (SBCL). So I'm wondering if there's a way to use an implementation's built in functionality to store the state of a thread and reload it later. Is this possible? How? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: The simplest idea I would try is to (i) do a bit of busy waiting with a channel for exchanging message with the main thread; it actually might not be too expensive. You can setup an event loop with a timer that periodically checks if the thread should stop (ii) call `(sb-thread:interrupt-thread thread function)` to execute a bit of code in the worker thread, e.g. signal a "pause" condition; once paused, the thread can block on read to resume its work. `save-lisp-and-die` is imo not the right tool here (https://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image)

Comment: save-lisp-and-die is definitely not a good match, as it does not work with multiple threads ("only a single thread may remain running after sb-ext:*save-hooks* have run" in the link by @coredump])